# SQL Query to Find Most Popular Instances of Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to build a query that will sort occurrences of the field DESCR254.  So for example, test1 is used by 3 different USERIDs and test2 would be the second most.  Does anyone know how I would construct this query given there are many more rows of data and many different instances of USERID and DESCR254?

select * from sysadm.PS_IS_STATS_URLS

PS_IS_STATS_URLS

```
USERID   DESCR254 
ZX       test1
ZX       test2
ZC       test1 
ZB       test3
ZA       test1
ZA       test2
```

I would want the result to look something like this:

```
DESCR254    COUNT
test1       3
test2       2
test3       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DESCR254, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM sysadm.PS_IS_STATS_URLS
GROUP BY DESCR254
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Comment: that looks right Steven, I'm running the query now and if it looks right I'll approve the answer and upvote.  There's a lot of data so it'll take a couple minutes :P

Answer (score 0):

To count only accesses from *different* userids as your question suggest, you need to use `COUNT DISTINCT`;

```
SELECT DESCR254, COUNT(DISTINCT USERID) "COUNT"
FROM PS_IS_STATS_URL
GROUP BY DESCR254
ORDER BY "COUNT" DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle with a non counted duplicate to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0216/1).